Execute the loop again if condition matches
Hi i am trying to run a loop again if condition matches
Below is my code if range matches to 10 then execute line-1 and line-2 again.
The complete below loop has to run for 50 times
    for x in range(1,11): #line - 1
        print(x)          #line - 2
        if x==10:
            <excute Line -1 & Line -2>

Any modifications , please suggest.
thanks in advance

What do you mean by executing line 1, which is a for statement, again? Do you mean to restart the for loop with x starting from 1 again, when x==10?

Thank you, Yes need to restart for loop again , same has to run 50 times

It's really not clear exactly what behavior you want. If you were to restart the loop every time x==10, you would end up with an infinite loop.

I want to stop at 50th time the entire loop

If you want your for loop to repeat 50 times, the easiest thing is to put it inside a for loop.
for _ in range(50):
    for j in range(10):
        print(j+1)

Though, I would probably use one loop and the modulo operator % to give the same result.
for j in range(50 * 10):
    print(j % 10 + 1)

